# Android KSOAP: Empty Response when passing parameters

Tags: java, android, ksoap

I'm trying to consume this web service: http://www.ezzylearning.com/services/CountryInformationService.asmx with KSoap.

When I call a web method (example: GetContinents) without parameters it work fine. When I try to use one with parameters it always return empty data.

Here is my Activity class (for testing purposes):

```
public class MyTestActivity extends Activity
    {
      private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://www.ezzylearning.com/services/";
      private static final String URL = "http://www.ezzylearning.com/services/CountryInformationService.asmx?WSDL";
      private static final String ACTION_GET_COUNTRIES_BY_CONTINENT = "http://www.ezzylearning.com/services/CountryInformationService.asmx/GetCountriesByContinent";
      private static final String METHOD_GET_COUNTRIES_BY_CONTINENT = "GetCountriesByContinent";    


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
     {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fourth);
    String property = "continentCode";
    String value = "AS";
    new GetCountriesByContinentTask().execute(URL, NAMESPACE, ACTION_GET_COUNTRIES_BY_CONTINENT, METHOD_GET_COUNTRIES_BY_CONTINENT, property, value);
   }

// Implementation of AsyncTask used get the countries by continent.
private class GetCountriesByContinentTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params)
    {
        String result = "Testing...";

        String url = params[0];
        String namespace = params[1];
        String action = params[2];
        String method = params[3];
        String property = params[4];
        String value = params[5];
        List<PropertyInfo> propertyList = new ArrayList<PropertyInfo>();

        //Use this to add parameters
        PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();
        pi.setName(property);
        pi.setValue(value);
        pi.setType(String.class);
        propertyList.add(pi);

        try
        {   
            MySoapHandler soapHandler = new MySoapHandler();
            SoapObject soapRresult = soapHandler.soapCall(url, namespace, action, method, propertyList);
            if (soapRresult != null)
            {
                System.out.println("RESULT: " + soapRresult.toString());  // THE DATA SET IS ALWAYS EMPTY     
            }
        } 
        catch (Exception ex) 
        {
            System.out.println("Exception: " + ex.getMessage());       
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }       

        return result;
    }

    @Override


    protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
        {
        }
    }
}
```

My Class for calling the web service:

```
public class MySoapHandler
{

public 
        public SoapObject soapCall(String url, 
                               String namespace, 
                               String action, 
                               String method, 
                               List<PropertyInfo> propertyInfoList)
    throws IOException, XmlPullParserException
    {
        //Initialize soap request
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(namespace, method);

    //Add parameters
    if(propertyInfoList != null)
    {
        for(PropertyInfo pi: propertyInfoList)
        {
            request.addProperty(pi);
        }
    }

    //Declare the version of the SOAP request
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    envelope.dotNet = true;

    //Call the webservice
    HttpTransportSE transport = new HttpTransportSE(url);
    transport.call(action, envelope);

    //Return the SoapResult from the envelope body.


return (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;
    }
}
```

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

I also tried to change **envelope.bodyIn** to **envelope.getResponse()**, but the dataset is still empty.

Thank you.

Comment: Try setting transport.debug = true and use httpTransportSE.requestDump, httpTransportSE.responseDump for seeing totally your request and server response

Comment: @kinghomer. Thanks for the help. The envelope request seems to be fine, but the response DataSet is always empty. I've tried test this on web SOAP client applications and the request is basically the same.

Comment: do u got solution ..i am also facing same problem

Comment: @ShakeebAyaz Try the following: private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://www.ezzylearning.com/services/CountryInformationService.asmx/GetCountriesByContinent";
private static final String METHOD_NAME = "GetCountriesByContinent";
private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://www.ezzylearning.com/services/CountryInformationService.asmx";
private static final String URL = "http://www.ezzylearning.com/services/CountryInformationService.asmx";

Comment: when am free definetly I will do it..any how I solved my issue